# How to use /etc/hosts in unbound DNS server?

Tags: openbsd

I followed the https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/example1.html to set up an unbound DNS nameserver on a box.

**Question**: how do I configure the unbound DNS server to also use the /etc/hosts file on the box? I have a few domains in it for adblocking and it resolvs them instead of just giving back 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I suspect that you need to configure the system resolver to use /etc/hosts first, then the local DNS server. I don't know how to do that on OpenBSD, but on most GNU/Linux systems, you'd poke around in /etc/nsswitch.conf to change the resolver ordering. Chances that anything resembling a proper DNS server would consult /etc/hosts are slim.

Comment: As others note, `unbound` will not use `/etc/hosts`.  If you want to use DNS misdirection for adblocking, then configure your `unbound.conf` to claim to be authoritative for the offending domains, with `local-data` lines pointing to 127.x.x.x

Answer (score 2):

On OpenBSD you need to add a line like this to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
lookup file bind
```

However, this affects only the `gethostbyname(3)` and `gethostbyaddr(3)` calls, not the `unbound` responses.  That is, it takes effect only for programs that run on the machine itself.  It won't work if other machines are configured to use `unbound` on the OpenBSD machine as a resolver.  To deal with that you'll probably need a HTTP proxy.